# Node.js — mongoose static method example

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I wish to define a method on a model `UserModel` such that I get the names of all the users that have userId < 10.

Following is my implementation:

```
// pseudo code
UserModel === {
    userId : Number,
    userName: String
}

UserSchema.statics.getUsersWithIdLessThan10 = function(){
    var usersLessThan10 = []
    this.find({userId : {$lt : 10}}, function(error, users){
        users.forEach(function(user){
            console.log(user.userName) // ... works fine
            usersLessThan10.push(user.userName)
        })
    })
    return usersLessThan10
}
```

I understand why this doesn't seem to work — async find API. But if that's the case, then whats the way to do it? This async stuff is kind of overwhelming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add callback and return the users in this callback as follows:

```
UserSchema.statics.getUsersWithIdLessThan10 = function(err, callback) {
    var usersLessThan10 = []
    this.find({userId : {$lt : 10}}, function(error, users){
        users.forEach(function(user){
            console.log(user.userName) // ... works fine
            usersLessThan10.push(user.userName)
        })
        callback(error, usersLessThan10)
    })
}
```

Then call `usersLessThan10` with the callback:

```
... .usersLessThan10(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
    console.log(users);
})
```

Comment: I don't need to log them. I just a need a list. I need something like:

`var users = getUsersWithIdLessThan10(..., ...)`

Comment: It seems that the method `find` is asynchronous so what you are asking is just not possible with it. You can do anything you want with `users` (not only `console.log`) but only in the asynchronous callback. You may post the rest of your code and ask for help on how to incorporate `getUsersWithIdLessThan10` but it is really not too much you can do with async methods...

Comment: If I create an API to just return a list of these usernames, what would I do? It's as simple as that.

Comment: This is joy of working with node. It is JavaScript and everything is asynchronous and works within one thread so it extremely fast and you like it but in a few weeks you will understand what the "callback hell" means.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**API code:**

```
var UserApi = require('./UserSchema');

var callback = function(response){
    console.log(response); // or res.send(200,response);
}

UserApi.getUsersWithIdLessThan10(callback);
```

**UserSchema code:**

```
UserSchema.getUsersWithIdLessThan10 = function(callback){
    var usersLessThan10 = []
    this.find({userId : {$lt : 10}}, function(error, users){
        if (error)
           { callback(error)}
        else{
          users.forEach(function(user){
              console.log(user.userName) // ... works fine
              usersLessThan10.push(user.userName);
              //TODO: check here if it's the last iteration
                 callback(usersLessThan10);
          })
        }
    })
}
```